# How do I access the TFS workspace of an employee that has quit to review/check in some of the changes?

Tags: tfs, workspace

One of my co-workers has resigned and was made to leave the premises before checking in all of his code to TFS. I have access to the physical files. Is there a way for me to access his workspace and check in some of the changes that are still left unchecked in? From tfs I can see which files he has checked out but no way of seeing the exact changes unless very manually.

Answer (score 14):

In TFS 2010, there is a new feature called 'Public Workspaces'. This allows multiple people to **share the same workspace folders** on a computer, but authenticating to TFS using their **own** logon.

A TFS administrator can change a workspace to a 'Public Workspace' by running a command like the following:

```
tf workspace /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/yourCollection WorkspaceName;domain\CurrentWorkspaceOwner /permission:Public
```

*(This command can be run on any computer, it doesn't need to be run on the same computer as the workspace you are trying to change)*

If there is only one other user that needs to use the workspace, perhaps a simpler method is to just change the owner of the workspace. This can be done by a TFS administrator with the following command:

```
tf workspace /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/yourCollection WorkspaceName;domain\CurrentWorkspaceOwner /newowner:domain\NewWorkspaceOwner
```

Once you have done either of these things, you can logon to that computer as the new owner and use the workspace as if it were your own.

You can read more about this feature in this blog post [TFS2010: Public Workspaces](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/11/08/tfs2010-public-workspaces.aspx).

Comment: @volody Run it from Visual Studio Command Prompt.  FYI.  It looks like you cannot change the owner if there are pending changes, but you can change the permission to Public and then check-in (or undo).

Answer (score 4):

**1)** Copy the files from his machine.

**2)** Administratively undo his checkout.

**3)** Check out the files on your machine.

**4)** Overwrite your files with his files.

**5)** Your machine state should now roughly equal his; do as many comparisons as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Have your sys-admin reset the users password to a known value, login as the user on that machine and voila, you are the user...

Comment: Not an option as that would violate some sort of privacy policy - don't ask me why.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a quick and dirty way of doing it:

- Shelve or check-in your own work.
- Copy the relevant files from your co-worker into your own workspace
- Compare the files with latest in TFS

//huusom

Comment: Is there a way to check out the files after I have copied them over to my workspace so it looks like exactly what he had before he left?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some diff tool like beyond compare to visualise the actual differences.

To manage others' workspaces and even checked out files it is hard to beat [Team Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/), which is free and provides brilliant interface for this and many other routine TFS work.